# Domain Class Functions vs. Service Functions [Grails]

Tags: grails, spring-mvc, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I need to save and update properties of different domain classes in one transaction.

I know I can use the following:

```
def addToChildren(String name, int age) {
    User.withTransaction {
        def user = new User(name)
        user.age = age
        user.save()

        def school = new School()
        school.addToUsers(user)
        school.save()
    }
}
```

1. Is it possible to use transactions like this in a domain model?
2. Where should I put the addToChildren function? Is it in the User class, the School class or some external place like a Service?
3. Should I use withTransaction or withNewTransaction?
4. Can I have transactions in model function?
5. Should addToChildren be a model function which calls a service function to modify the model properties?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grails services already are transactional, and it's the best place to manipulate domain classes. The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html) explains it:

> Services are typically involved with coordinating logic between domain
>   classes, and hence often involved with persistence that spans large
>   operations. Given the nature of services, they frequently require
>   transactional behaviour. You can use programmatic transactions with
>   the withTransaction method, however this is repetitive and doesn't
>   fully leverage the power of Spring's underlying transaction
>   abstraction.

So there's no need to use `withTransaction` inside them.

**EDIT**

> Where should I put the addToChildren function?

This is more a design decision you can declare you method in a domain class or in a service. Personally, when I manipulate more than one domain class I tend to do it in a service class, except when I need to use the GORM events: `beforeInsert()`, `beforeUpdate()` and `beforeDelete()`.

> Can I have transactions in model function?

Yes, you can use transactions / hibernate sessions in your domain class. A common example is the beforeDelete event:

```
class Person {
   String name
   def beforeDelete() {
      ActivityTrace.withNewSession {
         new ActivityTrace(eventName: "Person Deleted", data: name).save()
      }
   }
}
```

Since you're deleting a record, you need a new hibernate session to handle others inserts.

Comment: Ok, this does not answer my question. Where should I put the addToChildren function? Can I have transactions in model function? Should addToChildren be a model function which calls a service function to modify the model properties?

Comment: When should I use withNewSession and when withSession?

Comment: withSession use the same already opened session. Let's say you want to do a list of operations and in the end flush, then you use withSession. withNewSession is to use a new fresh session.

Comment: Can you give me examples when it is recommended to use withNewSession()?

Comment: @confile The example is in my answer, in the Person class.

Comment: Do you use withNewTransaction() only when you delete or create objects?

Comment: @confile you're confusing `withNewSession` and `withNewTransaction`. Use `withNewSession` in GORM events. I don't have a use case to `withNewTransaction`, but you can use it if you want to handle the status of your transaction like the [example in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html).

Comment: @confile I think the answer to your question cannot be more lucid and to-the-point than what we have above. Shouldn't related questions be new questions, so that the areas of yours/others excavations is not hidden in comments?